# Haskell Trouble with Lists

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to write a simple function that takes a list of integers and returns a list such that the first element is added to all the elements of the list.

This is what I have so far.

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl (x:xs) = [x + x | x <- xs]
```

Unfortunately all `this` has succeeded in doing is returning a list without the first element and the other elements being doubled.

Comment: just use a different name for the elements in `xs`

Comment: Thank you! However, the first element still gets removed from the returned list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binding of `x` in the list comprehension is hiding the variable `x` from the pattern. Try this instead:

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl (x1:xs) = [x1 + x2 | x2 <- xs]
```

**Edit**

In response to you comment

> the first element still gets removed from the returned list

In `(x1:xs)`,`xs` is the remainder or `tail` of the list. It is all the elements after `x1`, which is the `head`. If you want to add `x1` to all the elements including itself, you could write

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl (x1:xs) = [x1 + x2 | x2 <- (x1:xs)]
```

or in terms of `head`

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl xs = [head xs + x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: I really like the `head xs` version as it clearly expresses the intent.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea on the other hand `head` is a partial operation, hence every use of `head` adds a burden on the programmer -- namely, to prove that its argument is not null. By comparison, the first solution does not require any proof, and so is arguably simpler to use in a safe way.

Comment: @chi The proof that `xs` is non empty is trivially given by the fact there's a separate case for an empty xs above though.

Comment: @Cubic: And by the fact that the `head xs + x` part won't ever be executed if `xs` is empty.

Comment: Sure, in this case the proof is trivial. Still, it is harder to provide a trivial proof than no proof at all. In the general case the proof could be non trivial, and tools beyond standard type checking may help in establishing correctctess e.g. http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/catch/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl l@(x:_) = [x + x1 | x1 <- l ]
```

or

```
addFirstEl [] = []
addFirstEl l@(x:_) = map (+ x) l
```